# concurrent excel file writing

Tags: java, excel, synchronization

Is it possible to write a program in java where multiple resources can write into an excel sheet concurrently? Say for example, requests are comming in. For each request, 4 rows are updated. So when 70 users are accessing the file at the same time, 70*4 rows need to be updated simultaneously. When i tried it with synchronisation process, I encountered a issue with deadlock. Is it possible to achieve this without multithreading?

Comment: What if all users remake their own versions of same file, which one will be chosen to save on disk? Saving one on top of other just deletes the previous one's data. If you mean by changing different cells from different users, then it can be cached in memory and written only once. If all users write to "B5" cell, how can we choose which one updates B5?

Comment: The actual writing should be in 1 thread, but doesn't mean you can't wrap it in a queuing system whereby exposed methods are called from many threads.

Comment: But you can make a locking mechanism which locks some cells if they are accessed by a user. All other users see "access denied" on their screen for those cells until first user releases them.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik what you are telling is right if the users are entering data in same sheet. instead can a new sheet be allocated every time a new user wants to enter data, in the same workbook?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java nio package to allow multithreaded writing http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html
This package provides control within the file where each thread can fill the different regions. Other way is that you can synchronize your File object; this will give access to one thread at a time.

Comment: java.nio.channels.FileLock

Comment: Thanks for your info vels4j. java.nio is a great package, have to explore more.